# Nodejs - Save and reuse variable stored in one route with another route

Tags: node.js

I have this nodejs script that authenticates user login by validating inputs with values in a DB. Since the login happens just once, I want to be able to save some details from this route and have that re-used in other routes as long as the user session is active. Given below is my route for login that has two variables `user_email` and `user_name`.. When I console log when the login route runs, I am able to see the values. However when I call this in other routes, it says undefined.

I tried using express-session middleware for this but that did not help.

```
const session = require("express-session");

const secretKey = 123;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(
 session({
   secret: "123",
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: true,
 })
);
```

Login route code

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(service_url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: payload,
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    const data = await response.json();
    const user_email = data.user.emailAddress;
    const user_name = data.user.name;

    req.session.user_email = user_email;
    req.session.user_name = user_name;
    req.session.save();
```

Sample route I want to be able to re-use the stored variables `user_email` and `user_name`. But this returns undefined.

```
app.get("/route1/:name", async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params;
  console.log(req.session.user_name);
  console.log(req.session.user_email);
```